# Ruby client Eventbrite API finding event IDs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, events, client, eventbrite

How can I get the event id for use with the ruby eventbrite client?

The method I want to use is:

```
eb_client.event_get({id: 1848891083})
```

For a conventional url I can find it in the url:
http://www.eventbrite.com/event/**1894154467**/ehometext

Whereas what I'm looking for is when urls are like this:
http://tjf2012-ehometext.eventbrite.com/

EDIT:
Using The Javascript Console:

```
[18:03:32.221] window.eid
[18:03:32.232] "2809903497"
```

How can I use ruby to do that same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the situation that you are describing involves finding an event page using your web browser.  If that is the case, then the javascript console's window.eid, or the page's 'contact the host' link should include an eid, even when the event is using a custom subdomain url.

If you want to find the same event using ruby (instead of finding using your browser), then you should use the [event_search()](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/) method, which will automatically contain an 'id' attribute on each 'event' resource that is returned.

Another option might be to use organizer_list_events() to find events associated with a specific event organizer profile.  Or, try user_list_events() for accessing all events from a given user account.

Comment: my intention was for a user to send a url and have my server-side program to find the event using the url, but I ended up deciding to use javascript and send just the id